# Resize CSS property has no effect

Tags: html, css

I'm working on Bookmarklet. After removing not-important parts, I have bottom docking draggable window and I want to add resizing. I will probably do this by hand (using mouse down/move/up), but I want to know why `resize: both` property doesn't work.

I have code like this:

```html
<div class="shell-wrapper docking">
  <div class="shell-container">
    <nav>
      <span class="shell-dock"></span>
      <span class="shell-destroy">[x]</span>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="shell-mask"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.shell-wrapper nav {
    cursor: row-resize;
    color: #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-family: monospace;
    text-align: right;
    background: black;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: initial;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
.shell-container {
    position: fixed;
    background: black;
    z-index: 99999;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 150px;
}
.shell-wrapper .shell-destroy {
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
.shell-wrapper .shell-mask{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
    z-index: 100
}
.shell-wrapper.drag .shell-mask {
    display: block;
}
.shell-wrapper .shell-dock,
.shell-wrapper .shell-destroy {
    padding: 5px 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}
.shell-wrapper.docking nav {
    cursor: default;
}
.shell-wrapper .shell-dock::before {
    content: "[■]";
}
.shell-wrapper.docking .shell-dock::before {
    content: "[_]";
}
.shell-wrapper.docking .shell-container {
    bottom: auto;
    right: auto;
    top:  calc(var(--top, 0) * 1px);
    left:  calc(var(--left, 0) * 1px);
    width: calc(var(--width, 500) * 1px);
    height: calc(var(--height, 400) * 1px);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
    resize: both; /* this have no effect */
}
```

You can check the [Demo on CodePen](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/ExwpEwB?editors=0110).
The code uses jQuery but the question is not related. The problem is in CSS.

Comment: you need overflow:hidden with resize

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks, I miss that when looking on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize.

Comment: The resize is working for me OK (Edge, Windows10). What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Works fine for me when `overflow: hidden;` is added. I am on Chrome & Linux.

Comment: @AHaworth the code is fixed because I've added `overflow: hidden` please read the comments.

Comment: @カメロン the code is fixed because I've added `overflow: hidden` please read the comments.

Comment: I've deleted the property that fixes the issue on CodePen so I don't have comments that it works.

Comment: To avoid confusion you can add a snippet here instead of CodePen, using the `[<>]` button. This way you don't link to a fixed version. You can also close this question everything is fixed for you. Or is there still something buggy that needs solving?

Comment: @PeterKrebs yes, thanks for reminding.

Comment: For people that vote to close. Please explain what is unclear here? This is a question that was never asked that could be pretty common that has a simple answer. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @jcubic You wrote "The code is fixed because I've addded `overflow: hidden`" so people assume your problem is resolved. Please update the question or close this and create a new one.

Comment: @PeterKrebs This is a valid question, a valid problem, and the first comment is the solution. I don't understand what you want from me.

Comment: @jcubic Answers are typically posted below on this site, not as a 1-line-comment. To make you understand the platform: Your question seems to have no answers (no posted answer, no accepted answer). It seems your question still needs help. But it is solved. So it is a good idea to mark it as closed as there is no need of more help.